# How to serialize a field using nested relation with a serializer that also contain a nested relation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm working on django rest framework with writable nested serializers. Using the documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) i'm able to do a nested relationships using serializer as a field.

Here comes my problem. I got the error below when I'm trying to do a nested relation using a serializer as a field when this serializer has also a nested relation.

TypeError: Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use info_object.set() instead.

Here are a part of my serializer:

```
class BuildMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.BuildMessageInfo
        fields = '__all__'

class BuildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    info_object = BuildMessageSerializer(
        many=True,
        required=False,
        allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Build
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        infos_result = validated_data.pop('info_object')
        build_res = models.Build.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for info_result in infos_result:
            models.BuildMessageInfo.objects.create(
                build_res=build_res,
                **info_result)
        build_res.labels.set(infos_result)
        return build_res


class JobResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.JobResult
        fields = '__all__'


class JobBuildResult(JobResultSerializer):

    build_result = BuildSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        builds_data = validated_data.pop('build_result')
        job_result = models.JobResult.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for build_data in builds_data:
           models.Build.objects.create(job_result=job_result,**build_data)
        return job_result
```

You can find here the payload for my unit test:

```
self.build_payload = {
    'daily_key': '365v4a9e8fv4s9efb8',
    'computer': 'SOPBAMBOO01',
    'branch_name': 'branch',
    'plan_key': 'key',
    'build_number': 25,
    'pull_request': False,
    'build_result': [
        {
            'name': 'app',
            'project': 'ble',
            'platform': 'board',
            'mode': 'release',
            'os': 'bm',
            'ide': 'iar',
            'result': 'pass',
            'warning': 0,
            'error': 0,
            'info_object': [
                {
                    'message_type': 'message',
                    'message': 'message',
                    'log_link': 'message'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know how to manage this error. I'm new to django and I also don't understand what the error mean by use info_object.set()

Thanks for any help

Comment: No time for proper answer but your problem is located in this line: `models.Build.objects.create(job_result=job_result,**build_data)`. At this point `build_data` contains an array of `BuildMessageInfo` objects and Django does not support assigning relations in this way. It looks like you think that line would end up calling the `create()` method of your `BuildSerializer` but it will not

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment ! Well, yes that something like that I thought...How can I manage this thought ? Do I have to rewrite my serializers in a different way ?